# Run a docker container in a new interactive terminal with sshpass!

Tags: bash, ssh, docker, gnome-terminal, sshpass

I'm trying to run a Docker container in a new interactive terminal with sshpass. I've found that:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -- sh -c \
 "sshpass -p "password" ssh name@ip -t 'bash -ic docker run ...';bash'"
```

Where password,name,ip, are the correct ones and ... is the rest of the docker command(mounts, group_id etc.)

The command works and creates a new terminal with the right container inside. The problem is that it's not interactive, so stopping the execution with ctrl-c (SIGINT) interrupts the sshpass command and the container remains running in the remote server. The idea is to make this work to execute the command for many instances.

PS: How can I give in the script the name,ip and password from a $variable? The usual way it's not working correctly.

Comment: You seem to be running an interactive `bash` command through SSH without an interactive `docker-run` command.  To interact with the `bash` in the just run Docker container, you may need to add the run options `--interactive` and `--tty`.  Also, please explain what you are trying to achieve with the `;bash` at the end.  I would think the semicolon separates `bash` from the rest of the `docker run` command.

Comment: With the ;bash in the end (which is given as command to ssh) when the container has finished running the ssh connection remains open in the bash and doesn't close. The problem occurs with SIGINT that closes the connection but in the meanwhile keeps the container remotely running. A solution could be to stop it autonomously if the connection closes after SIGINT, but I don't know how to say that in this command line (or in the container code).